# Where can i find a users profile settings in the Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Im currently exploring Facebook Android SDK, looking for a way to change a users personal settings.

E.g: Secure browsing, Login notification and so on.

I have been searching the web and browsed through the SDK but i cant find this information anywhere. I am not looking for code, just want to know where to access these settings, can it be done through Facebooks SDK?

Comment: Gut feeling: not allowed since you could abuse that.

Comment: I guess you are right, but how do they do it here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trendmicro.socialprivacyscanner&hl=en